# Trajectory of a particle under certain forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces

Earth is revolving around the sun. Now what will happen to the trajectory of earth when we apply equal and opposite forces  perpendicular to r on the earth and the sun?

"r is the distance between the earth and the sun"

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the earth and sun form a two body system,rotating about their barycentre. However for most calculation puroposes, you can take the sun to be at rest. Now, r is the mean distance of the earth from the sun, which means $r = \frac {r_a + r_ b}{2}$ where $r_a$ and $r_b$ denote min and max distances of the elliptical orbit. Therefore, the major axis length of the orbit is $a = 2r$. Now wr knoe that the total energy of the  system is given by $E= -\frac{GM}{a}$. Now a tangential thrust at a certain point will only change the kinetic energy part of E. Substitute the changed E, and find the new major axis length a'. This is a common maneuvere used in increasing the orbital speed of spacecrafts, before finally slinging them out towards the desired target. The Mangalayaan used this principle.

Comment: Since this is basically an excercise type question, i'll let you derive the equatiom for E yourself.

Comment: Also note, you can apply this to the sun's elliptic orbit as well about the common barycentre, but in that case you will have the calculate the common barycentre position, and modify your major axis length likewise.